# URL Query params builder

Tags: c++, c++11, url

My goal is to create a URL query params from `std::map<std::string, std::string>`. For example, we call `to_query_params( {{"one","1"},{"two","2"}} )` and we get `?one=1&two=2`.

Is this a good way of doing it?

```
std::string to_query_params(std::map<std::string, std::string> map)
{
    if (map.empty()){
        return "";
    }
    auto map_beg = std::begin(map);
    auto concat = [](const decltype(map)::value_type& a){
                        return a.first+"="+a.second;
                    };
    std::string result("?"+concat(*map_beg));
    std::for_each(std::next(std::begin(map)), 
                  std::end(map), 
                  [&](decltype(map)::value_type param){ 
                      result+="&"+concat(param); 
                  });
    return result;
}
```

Comment: What kind of feedback are you interested in? Performance, readability, general feedback?

Comment: Performance, readability and maintenance.

Answer (score 2):

You are not performing any [percent encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) of parameter names or values, which would likely lead to breakage or even a security vulnerability if the you are given parameters that contain a special character.

A `std::map` might not be the right type; a `std::multimap` may be more appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

- Give your operators some breathing space:

  ```
  return a.first + "=" + a.second;
  ```
- Concatenation involves constructing and deleting many temporary strings. `std::stringstream` avoids it:

  ```
  std::stringstream result;
  ...
  result << '&' << a.first << '=' << a.second;
  ...
  return result.str();
  ```
- Pass `map` by reference.

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason to use decltype

```
auto concat = [](const decltype(map)::value_type& a){
                    return a.first+"="+a.second;
                };
```

Why not use `auto`

```
auto concat = [](auto const& a){
                    return a.first+"="+a.second;
                };
```

Don't special case the '?' Just use '&' then change the one character after you have finished.

```
std::string to_query_params(std::map<std::string, std::string> map)
{
    if (map.empty()){
        return "";
    }
    std::string result;
    std::for_each(std::begin(map), 
                  std::end(map), 
                  [&](auto const& param){ 
                      result+="&"+concat(param); 
                  });
    // Just convert the first '&' into '?'
    result[0] = '?';
    return result;
}
```

The reason for this is that you use different techniques for both cases by only using one you make sure your code is DRY and consistent.

```
 // Version 1 parameter:
 const decltype(map)::value_type&

 // Version 2 parameter:
 decltype(map)::value_type          // different.
```

Also:

```
 // Vesion 1
 return a.first+"="+a.second;

 // Version 2:
 result+="&"+concat(param);    // concat or + "="
```

But rather than using a lambda we can use a range based for loop.

```
    std::string result;
    std::for(auto const& value: map) 
        result += "&" + concat(value); 
    );
```

I would probably use a `std::map<std::string, std::vector<std::string>>` that's because parameters in the URL allow multiple values and their order is significant.

Comment: "Why not use auto in lambda" - because it's c++11 :)